# How do I stop my downloaded images from falling down my table?

Tags: excel, vba

I have created a tool using VBA that takes a spreadsheet input and generates a PDF report output. Part of this report includes pictures which are hosted online, with the link to these images stored in the cell.

Part of the code of this tool downloads these images and places them over the cell holding the link, formatting them to the preset dimensions of the cell (100 x 100px)

When each cell in the image column has a picture link, the code works fine. However, not all line items in the report have an image attached to them.

When this happens, the last image before the blank cell will be placed in the last blank cell before the next image link, essentially 'dropping down' to the wrong place in the report.

I've tried tinkering with the code, to no avail. I have come up with a temporary fix of formatting the cells with IFBLANK(link to image of white square) so that this white square is insterted to give the appearance of a blank cell, however this requires the user to keep an image of a white square and refer to it directly in the code, or for the white square to be hosted on a permanently active site, which I am not comfortable with. I would like this tool to be as future proofed as possible so that others can continue using it.

```
    'Download Images
    Dim Pshp As Shape
    Dim xRg As Range
    Dim xCol As Long

    On Error Resume Next

    Set Rng = Sheets("POMEC Report").Range(Sheets("POMEC DATA").Range("R6"))

    For Each Cell In Rng
        filenam = Cell
        ActiveSheet.Pictures.Insert(filenam).Select
        Set Pshp = Selection.ShapeRange.Item(1)

        If Pshp Is Nothing Then GoTo lab

        xCol = Cell.Column
        Set xRg = Cells(Cell.Row, xCol)

        With Pshp
            .LockAspectRatio = msoFalse
            .Width = 100
           .Height = 100
            .Top = xRg.Top + (xRg.Height - .Height) / 2
            .Left = xRg.Left + (xRg.Width - .Width) / 2
        End With
lab:
        Set Pshp = Nothing

    Next
```

I have a helper cell in another tab that calculates the last row of data in the report so I can make the range dynamic (POMEC Report R6), but this error occurs even when this range is hardcoded.

What am I doing wrong to cause this? Any help is greatly appreciated!

Comment: Note that you cannot debug your code because of `On Error Resume Next`. This line hides all error messages, but the errors still occur.  Since you cannot see the messages you cannot fix the errors, and your code might not do what you expect. Remove that line, see which errors you get and fix them.

Comment: @Pᴇʜ Thank you! I now get Run-time error '1004'; "Unable to get the Insert property of the Picture class" and the macro stops running at the first blank.

Comment: What do you mean by *"stops running at the first blank"*? And in which line does the error occur?

Comment: By "stops running at the first blank" I mean that the pictures will only be inserted down to where the first empy cell is instead of all cells in the range. The error occurs at "ActiveSheet.Pictures.Insert(filenam).Select"

Comment: So either test if `filenam` is empty like eg `If filenam = "" Then Goto lab` or even better test if the filename `filenam` exists.

Comment: I have modified part of the code to include

`If filenam = "" Then
        GoTo lab
        Else
        ActiveSheet.Pictures.Insert(filenam).Select
        Set Pshp = Selection.ShapeRange.Item(1)
        End If`

But I still get the same error message. I'm not sure how to make it ignore the empty cells.